# How to add same onClickListener in every textView in android dialog?

Tags: android

I have a custom android dialog which has several textViews. each textview is showing a different text. The intention is when user clicks on a textview, the dialog should be closed and the textColor of that textview should be returned to the parent.

This is my dialog layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="White"
    android:id="@+id/textView_white"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#fffffbfd" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Black"
    android:id="@+id/textView_black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:password="false"
    android:background="#ff000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am launching the dialog this way from the parent activity:

```
        final Context context = MyWidgetConfigureActivity.this;
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.color_chooser);
        dialog.setTitle("Choose Text Color");

        dialog.show();
```

I want to add same onClickListener to every textView inside the dialog. How to acheive this? There are 20+ textViews in the dialog, I dont want to add onClickListener to each textViews manually? is there any better way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two ways, first I would set a id for each TextView, then use the method `dialog.findViewById(id)` to get each TextView, and set a onClickListener, but I think this way is a pain in the neck.  So the second way is: firstly give the dialog layout root view a id, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_root"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000">
```

then the java code is:

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_root);
for (int i = 0; i < rootLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) rootLayout.getChildAt(i);
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

...
the onClick method is something like this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int color = ((TextView) v).getCurrentTextColor();
    // TODO ...
}
```

Comment: This is working fine :-) thank you, can you please let me know how do I close the dialog once an item has been clicked?

Comment: use the dialog.dismiss() in the onClick

Answer (score 1):

```
OnClickListener click = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"You can use", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(id);
TextView t2 = (TextView)findViewById(id);
TextView t3 = (TextView)findViewById(id);

t1.setOnClickListener(click);
t2.setOnClickListener(click);
t3.setOnClickListener(click);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change your approach. If you have 20+ TextViews which probably look the same, why not use ListView? Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

Comment: Hi Mighter, each textViews have different colors. they are not same.

Comment: why can't you set colors in listView?